# Where does Intellij store Github sessions / How to reokve all Git sessions

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I just started using an alt account for IJ and things immediately goes out of hand.

At the start of the day, I had two accounts (foo, the intended / bar, from last sprint) in ...

`Version Control > Github`

Then I tried to push, with the intension of using the foo account

```
19:23:59.917: [foo-repo] git -c http.sslBackend=schannel -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master --set-upstream
remote: Permission to foo/foo-repo.git denied to bar.
```

After one Google search I udpated my default account according to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/github.html

Still the same message, weird. I tried each of the following and nothing changed.

- Remove literally all accounts in `Version Control > Github`
- Double check both the project and global gitconfig doesn't specify anything related to `[user]`
- `Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Password` clear keepass database.
- Ditto, but switched to `Do not save, forget passwords after restart`. Invalidate IJ cache & restart
- Logout from all other Github related apps running on my PC

I am really scared about my privacy by this point since it seems that IJ remains access to my second account `bar` against all my best intensions and efforts (Like, it shouldn't even have any legitimate means to access `bar` by this point`). I would really love to get rid of anything related to Github from IJ. Where should I lookup to?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using credentials helper AND Chrome autofill was the problem, nothing to do with IJ iteslf.